MUI IP address input
Id like to create an input field for IP address with possibility to capture focus for every parts of the IP address, to edit them individually(like in DateInput fields for day, month, year).
There is a way to achieve it? Ideally with a combination of a MUI Textfield.
I was able to mask a MUI TextField with iMask library to show and validate the input. But this is only representation.
Found a library iput, it works like that, but cant copy and paste the IP address as a whole,  because internally it uses 4 input fields formatted to appear as one.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
